# stream-error #2032

Tags: apache-flex, rsl

I'm new to flex and since monday  I have a problem with the flex-application I'm maintaining. It seems  that the spark-component tries to load some runtime-shared-libraries  from the adobe-downloader-server, which are apparently (no longer?)  existing (stream-error #2032). One of those files, that were missing, was looked up under:  http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.0.0.13495/osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swf  (iirc)

The other missing files were: rpc_4.1.0.16076.swf, spark_4.1.0.16076.swf, sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swf, textLayout_1.1.0.604.swf

I  avoided the problem by downloading the related files and providing them  on the server, but wondered, why no one else seems to have those  problems.
My theory is, that those files were exisiting and  are now deleted for some reasons, but I just can't find any info on  that. Does anyone know what did happen?If my theory is right and those files were deleted, where does Adobe communicate such heavy steps?

Thanks

Comment: Adobe provides SWZ files for the Flex Framework.  These are signed RSLs which include the framework code and can be cached by the Flash Player across domains. When creating a release build--with RSLs enabled--the SWZ files will also be created for you.  If, for some reason they can't be downloaded from Adobe, the local copies will be used. Since you said your code is trying to download SWF files from Adobe; something is wrong. I'm not sure if you made a typo or there is something else odd at play.  I'm also not sure why you were trying to deploy your app without the extra files.